# ExoPlayer before API 16

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview, exoplayer

I need to have a VideoView in my app. I recently learned that people don't use VideoView for professional development; instead, they use ExoPlayer. But the apparent problem with ExoPlayer is that it requires API-16. My skills are presently a bit limited. I want a Video Player similar with Youtube: with the nice "overlay", etc. But I want to support API-10 if at all possible. Any ideas how I might do that? Google already disclaims that ExoPlayer is not yet part of the platform and so I think that means no support version as yet. So how do people overcome this hurdle presently?

Comment: Why would we downvote this question while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075116/youtube-video-playback-with-exoplayer has 12 up-votes? Again with the senseless down votes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do.  The main problem that ExoPlayer solves is providing a stable, pluggable solution for adaptive streaming.  If your needs don't require you to support adaptive streaming, then you should be find just using the native media player.  If you do require adaptive streaming, there are pay solutions available, such as Brightcove, however these solutions are expensive and likely won't support all the way down to SDK 10.